# asp.net: 2 column listbox with option to edit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net web application. the listbox has a data source of one field. it has 10 items. i want the user to be able to add a comment for every (or for specific) items. so i would like a listbox or combobox with 2 fields. one field will be the list of items and the other field will be blank and will allow user input.

does such a control already exist? the solution can be c#, asp.net, jquery.

i understand that this can be done with gridview, but can you please tell me how i can make one field read only and the other field editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @Joshua Smith 's suggestion...

ASP.NET

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server"></asp:Button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

C#

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Save the Text for user entered in Textbox1 for selected Value from List
        }
```

***Updated...***

**GridView Control with DropdownList and textBox**

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Option">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" Width="100px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Please check the following link, it might be useful for you:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AccessingControlsInsideGr.aspx

Comment: i understand that this can be done with gridview, but can you please tell me how i can make one field read only and the other field editable?

Comment: Paste the new code updated above in your aspx file. DropdownList will be always readonly and the text box is editable.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me it would be much simpler to use a table.  Put your data items in the first column, and text fields in the second column.

```
<table>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<tr>
<td>@item.someString //this is the data you want to display
</td>
<td>@Html.Editor("YourInputVariableName")
</td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: sorry i do not understand how you put html and c# together :)

Comment: I think, I__ wants solution for ASP.NET Web Forms, not ASP.NET MVC

Comment: See below, Scorpion has provided the correct solution for you I believe

Comment: @lucas i understand that this can be done with gridview, but can you please tell me how i can make one field read only and the other field editable?

Comment: @joshu  i understand that this can be done with gridview, but can you please tell me how i can make one field read only and the other field editable?